# What effect does this CSS code have on a wordpress website?

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to confirm what effect this CSS code has on the homepage of a wordpress website.

```
.lazy { display: none !important; }
```

Many thanks for explanations.

I have noticed images in the homepage are being blocked from being displayed which is why im asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS code itself, prevent any element which has it from being displayed on the screen.

Due to its name, it may be used to enable something called lazyload (you can read about it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/&ved=2ahUKEwitwqeytLHkAhWRTBUIHYERBXcQFjAJegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2W7B7Gra30pfjyO8lMxRRY)).
lazyload is usually used for several reasons:

1. Remove the pressure of loading many images at first; sometimes images are placed at the end of the page so the client won't see it at the top of the page, with lazy loading trick it. You can prevent those images from being loaded, and force them to load only the moment your client reach them by scrolling or other events so it cause page loading improvements (because the page is now lighter)
2. For making some visual effects; almost everywhere you need the image to be hidden and after some juggling or some specific events it is shown (like wp-admin and sub-menus, which will be shown if you hold your mouse on or click them)
3. etc
   Recording to the reasons; I guess your kind of codes (which will be handled in client-side and client browser) does not fit the first reason and may be used for the second one because for the first reason it is better (and I guess it must) implemented on server-side. Why? Because in your code, the image is loaded and be will there and just not shown because of the CSS code

This was all I know but if you want a more specific answer you have to say where you saw it in WordPress, in a plugin, wp-admin, template, etc...

Hope the answer becomes handy for you

Comment: Hey! I know it's been a while since you posted this, but I just wanted to say something. Refrain from using "u" and "ur". Those are mainly for texting friends or something. I requested an edit for those to be fixed and just waiting for it to be accepted. Thanks!